# Unity Rewarded Interstitial with Google Mobile Ads v6.0.2 - code from tutorial doesn't work

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, ads, interstitial, google-mobile-ads

I am trying to add an ad to my game in Unity, but unfortunately using the example in the official google guide (developers.google.com/admob/unity/rewarded-interstitial), I get an error. Can anybody help me solve this problem?

[image]

```
public void Start()
{
    string adUnitId;
    #if UNITY_ANDROID
    adUnitId = trueRewardedAdId;
    #elif UNITY_EDITOR
    adUnitId = fakeRewardedAdId;
    #else
    adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
    #endif

    // Create an empty ad request.
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
    // Load the rewarded ad with the request.
    // Create an interstitial.
    RewardedInterstitialAd.LoadAd(adUnitId, request, AdLoadCallback);
}

private void AdLoadCallback(RewardedInterstitialAd ad, string error)
{
    if (error == null)
    {
        rewardedInterstitialAd = ad;

        rewardedInterstitialAd.OnAdFailedToPresentFullScreenContent += HandleAdFailedToPresent;
        rewardedInterstitialAd.OnAdDidPresentFullScreenContent += HandleAdDidPresent;
        rewardedInterstitialAd.OnAdDidDismissFullScreenContent += HandleAdDidDismiss;
        rewardedInterstitialAd.OnPaidEvent += HandlePaidEvent;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't use rewarded ads, but I use Unity and I tell you that in versions 6.0.0, 6.0.1 and 6.0.2 there are several errors. Try 5.4.0 which is the most stable at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Update LoadAd() to use an action as a parameter, and change the parameter 'error' type from string to AdFailedToLoadEventArgs in the callback.

```
public void Start()
{
   ...
    RewardedInterstitialAd.LoadAd(adUnitId, request, (req,err) => 
adLoadCallback(req, err));
}

private void AdLoadCallback(RewardedInterstitialAd ad, AdFailedToLoadEventArgs error)
{
  ...
}
```